# i have written this code and but it's not working properly

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a code that accepts a string of length as much a user want and displays it.so this is what I have written

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
  char *a;
  int i,n;
  a=(char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));
  printf("enter the string\t");
  for(i=0;a[i]!=0;i++)
  {
        scanf("%[^0]c",&a[i]);
        n=2+i;
        a=(char*)realloc(a,(n)*sizeof(char));
  }
  for(i=0;a[i]!=0;i++)
  {
        printf("%c",a[i]);
  }
  free(a);
  a=NULL;
}
```

but it's not entering into the loop and accepts any input. can you tell me what's going wrong? THANKS

Comment: Why are you printing character by character instead of putting this into a NULL-terminated string buffer and just feeding that to `printf` directly? While `free(a)` is understandable, setting `a` to `NULL` is really pointless.

Comment: Normally you'd tackle this problem by allocating an optimistically large buffer and if the user exceeds that size, reallocate with double the size. This avoids relentless reallocation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: `scanf("%[^0]c",&a[i])` is not a valid format. I suggest you use `fgets` and reallocate in steps of say 100 bytes, and repeat until the `'\n'` newline is detected at the end of the input string. Note that `'\0'` does not terminate input strings, but only C strings.

Comment: Please don't edit your question from errors pointed out. Rolled back.

Comment: @WeatherVane `scanf("%[^0]c",&a[i])` is a valid format, yet certainly not what OP wants.

Comment: @chux yes, I phrased it poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not entering the loop because you allocated `a` with `calloc`, so `a[0]` is 0.  It will fail the initial `a[i]!=0` test of both of your `for` loops.

Comment: but malloc() is also not solving the problem

Comment: for strings of small length, it's working correctly but as the length grows it's stops working

Comment: That's a separate problem.  I explained why you weren't entering the loops.  If you need more help please edit and update your question.